# DNS check showing Failed

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-dns

Domain Controller OS - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. The Name of the Server is QSIT035V2
Can you tell me why i am receiving "QSIT035V2 failed test DNS" Error?
Please see the print-screen Attached for more detail.
[image]

Comment: Can you give us more detail?  Such as # of DCs and OS type, whether Windows Firewall or 3rd party firewall or a/v is enabled, whether the dcdiag test works on other DCs, and ipconfig /all on the DC?  The RPC error is where I'm getting at, but there can be multiple reasons for it.

Comment: Is the local DNS service running and set as your DNS address in your NIC? If so, what version of Windows is running the DNS service?